Why does Intelligent Design support God more than aliens?
Throughout this question, let's assume that Intelligent Design is true.
People sometimes use Intelligent Design to conclude that God must exist. However, it seems to me that Intelligent Design can only be used to conclude that an intelligent designer exists. Why should we then think that this intelligent designer is God as opposed to the possibility that it was an advanced alien?

It might be better to ask this question on a forum for Christian theology.

It doesn’t. If anything, advanced aliens designing something (if ID was legitimate) is much more likely than god. For one, god is a very advanced being but without supposed physical psrts. A physical alien who would in turn have evolved from simpler processes Is much more plausible. However, there is currently no evidence to suggest that either of these hypotheses are needed to explain anything

Intelligent design of what? The inference is ubiquitous but the likely designer, if any, depends on what is supposed to be designed. When archeologists find an artifact they do not conclude that the intelligent designer was either God or aliens. If they found it on another planet or to be beyond any human technology then they might infer aliens. And if the 'artifact' is everything that exists then neither humans nor aliens, however advanced, do not quite measure up to the task.

What if God is a really advanced alien?

@A-LevelStudent Intelligent design is questionable, God is questionable, and aliens are questionable. Your question combines all three concepts. Why to expect that the question has a reliable answer?

It is outrageous that this question was closed. It is perfectly clear what is being asked.

Because that;'s a goal of ID - to wrap religious views into pseudo scientific wrapping for modern people. Basically it's religious marketing - why aliens then? It's not meant to search for some other "designers' its goal to spread religious views. It's pretty clear - just look at its proponents. :)

@Groovy ID changes God from an artist to an engineer. All this does is alter the job description. Instead of a creator whose mere thought is instantly materialized into existence you now have an engineer who methodically plans and designs with a purpose and rules that must be obeyed.

Positing an advanced alien only leads to a regression.  Just as positing that life on Earth stemmed from life that arrived from elsewhere in the universe only raises the question how it arose in that elsewhere.  Also, the "intelligent alien" requires you to explain how the alien life differs from earth life such that the alien's life shows no signs of intelligent design. Given that it's entirely hypothetical, that would be difficult to pull off, and it multiplies hypotheses.
Additionally, this is positing that the alien can either set up life to unfold like clockwork from its origin, or else can continually intervene in life on earth without leaving unequivocal traces of its origin.  That is, a third hypothesis that the alien has God-like powers while still being a natural being subject to all the laws of nature.

I didn't downvote, and don't see why this question got downvoted, but I'll note that ID doesn't argue that it is impossible for any life to arise without intelligent design, only that the kind of life we see on Earth couldn't have arisen that way.

In fact, I dislike anonymous downvotes so much I'm going to upvote just to counter them.

@local, thank you. Now Mary can try to improve her answer based on your comment if she want to. I believe the point she was trying to make is that just saying "intelligent design" only pushes the problem back, it doesn't answer the question of where life came from. As I noted, it isn't the goal of ID to give an ultimate explanation of where life in general came from; the goal of ID is to talk about earth life.

The goal of ID is to come up with excuses for why claims made by many Christians are irreconcilable with certain scientific discoveries. Part of that program is denying that that's what they're doing.

@JonathanZ - I believe your comment gets to the heart of the matter - the socio-political context and the manipulative strategy of ID proponents. There was once a good-faith, intellectually honest philosophical discussion about ID -- and some individuals today may also still be in good faith about it -- but really that discussion ended more than a century ago. (Also in modern protestant and catholic theology ID arguments are shrugged off and not taken seriously anymore -- for good reason. It's only in fundamentalist/sectarian Christian/Jewish/Islamic movements that it still is defended.)

@local  What it is actually observing is that it is multiplying hypotheses beyond necessity.

@tkruse Do remember, the world is about 20 times (2000%) as big aa USA. And hot issues in USA like ID might be overshadowed by ones that are hotter for the rest of the world

Well, it pretty simple as I see it.
Intelligent Design has strong ties to religious traditions, particularly within Christianity. Its supporters come from backgrounds where belief in God is foundational. So for many guys, it just serves as a way to insert religious beliefs into scientific discussions. By framing the complexity of life as evidence of a designer, they can advocate for the existence of God without directly citing religious texts.
And why then propose aliens as the intelligent designers? The primary goal is to validate a pre-existing belief in God, not to expand the discussion to include other intelligent beings. Intelligent Design functions as a religious argument cloaked in scientific language rather than a bona fide scientific theory - that's crucial point to understand why it even exists.

you can't make church have lessons. But you can make public schools have correct and good lessons.

Yep. Now we just need a universally accepted definition of "good and correct". It all gets rather tiresome. If we put divisive issues to a vote, they seem to come out close to 50-50 very often in the past few decades worldwide. I start to understand why the churches have divided in to so many distinct groups. But for a society to do that is fatal. Don't people understand that? Agreement may be more important than correctness, in some sense.

I won't be surprised if a successful clown wins again. It looks so called "simple Americans" like him. They voted for him before, why not again?

This "answer" is just an extended ad hominem argument, designed to rationalize avoiding considering the question itself.  Whatever the motives are of the ID movement, considering its claims anyway is, in the paraphrased words of Aristotle, the mark of an educated mind.

To expand a bit on the answer by @Mary: aliens as an explanation only puts off the problem, but doesn't solve it. Indeed, aliens are just a part of the nature (even if extended beyond the Earth). Thus, if aliens are accepted as an explanation, one now has to explain where the aliens came from, and most of the ID arguments against spontaneous evolution on Earth can be applied to aliens or/and evolution elsewhere in the Universe (or the Universe as a whole.)
On the other hand, God is a supernatural being, which we cannot comprehend. More specifically, the ID critiques of any natural process are by definition not applicable to God. It is a deus ex machina solution to the (supposed) inconsistency of scientific theories of evolution, human origin, big bang, etc.

@ScottRowe It is not clear which "context" you refer to.

@ScottRowe number of universes is like aliens - it doesn't change the essence of the problem, merely kicks the can down the road. Supernatural means that it is not susceptible to scientific study (unlike natural phenomena).

It is hard to distinguish between what is “hard to understand” and what does not exist

It depends on what you mean by the assumption that ID is true. Which particular variant of ID?
If you mean the claim that the Universe as a whole must have been designed, then that would seem to rule out aliens, assuming, by aliens, you mean intelligence from another part of the Universe.
If, on the other hand, you mean the claim that some agency must have had a hand in influencing the early stages of the evolution of life, then you might argue that points to aliens, on the grounds that an omnipotent God might either not be in the least concerned about the status of some primordial soup on a backwater of a planet, or that such a God would have played a far more bold stroke, perhaps creating a man whole, and maybe taking one of his ribs to make a woman.
Of course, neither options stands up to a moment's critical thought.

There are varying claims made by ID, and they have different consequences as to whether ID might support aliens or a divine creator.

Claims that the process of chemical evolution of proteins is too
complex to be accomplished by natural variations:


This is not really consistent with either.  Protein evolution is part of every successful mutation, not just speciation.  Aliens tweaking every viral evolution, and every animal evolution, few of which seem to have any "purpose", would require a massive degree of intervention in every species, continually, for billions of years.  The degree of effort by aliens would be implausible.  Alternatively, a Deity explicitly intervening to create mega gazillions of minor mutations every year is the opposite of what one would expect from an optimizing designer.  That such a designer emulates the unplanned/random phenomena we would expect if ID were wrong about how difficult it is to make proteins is -- unjustifiable.


ID claims Complex cellular sub-structures like flagella could not develop naturally, so they have to be designed biochemical machines:


This could be either aliens or a divine creator.  The relatively simple nature of these machines tend to make much more sense for an alien designer, because a divine creator could have built life in a final form from top to bottom.  There is no good reason for a divine creator to only build cellular sub-systems then wait for a very slow evolution process to take it from there, not build up all of life, as in creationism.


ID claims that the wide diversity of animals in the Cretaceous period, with no precursors, indicates a planned creation event.


The large number and complexity of Cretaceous animal species, and higher tiers, once more would require a massive design effort by aliens.  A divine creator basically would be needed to handle the workload.  However, the outcome of the period, in which almost all of these species and even higher branches died out, and were replaced by evolved vertebrates that we DO have the evolutionary history for, would be nonsensical for a divinely designed and planned sequence.  The cretaceous diversity is much more reasonably explained by the prior branching of the cretaceous life before the cretaceous period, but the branching was while they were all soft bodied, so that prior fossils did not show visible structure.  The mystery of why all these life independently developed hard structures simultaneously is possibly answerable by a natural event that released access to calcium.


ID notes that abiogenesis has not succeeded as a research programme, stalling after the Urey-Miller experiment. The chemical and structural complexity of simultaneously or sequentially developing DNA, RNA, a protein dynamic equilibrium, and a set of semi-permeable membranes, appears to be beyond what natural processes can achieve.


Either aliens or a divine creator could have developed the first protocell, then let evolution run after that.  As with bio machines, this makes a lot more sense for aliens than for a divine creator, who could have gotten by without evolution at all.


Our universe is fine tuned for life, as the constants of the
Standard Model could have been wildly different, and except for very
narrow ranges, most values would not allow complexity or a long
period of reactions in their resulting universes.  Note that this argument relies upon abiogenesis and evolution being able to create life under complexity plus time, so is somewhat incompatible with the others.


Aliens are not likely to be able to set the physics constants of a universe, so this one is pretty much limited to divine creators.

This track record is mixed.  Two of the claims make more sense for aliens, one for a divine creator, and two really make no sense either way.

All these claims are basically "god of the gaps" stuff. We don't know exactly how it works, then it's God! 2k years it was about lightning, now about specific nuances in proteins. But conceptually it's the same "logic". You don't need to go into any details of the claims, the same principle applies.

@Groovy -- Your claim is not true.  Tests for design are not an "X of the gaps", for any X.  The two failed cases I noted for both alien and divine options are failed because the intentionality part of design is not satisfied.  Meanwhile, an "we have no idea now, but maybe we will someday find a mechanistic explanation for this" is very much a "materialism of the gaps" answer.

@ScottRowe -- I am an empiricist.  I consider materialism and physicalism to both be empirically refuted.  wishing they weren't -- is not a good way to proceed to the next step in building a valid worldview.  I agree that an omni-God worldview would be emotionally and motivationally crippling for me at least.  Fortunately, I think that is empirically refuted too.

@Groovy "God of the gaps", or a vision the big picture and willingness to accept a model that integrates a wide variety of phenomena in a coherent manner?  Are you familiar with the parable of the blind men and the elephant?

ID is not an author, and has no central theory from which such claims follow. So this list is not a the model of ID, but a collection of most successful affack vectors in science glued together by the answerer. There are many other claims, which were less successful, but which were not less vehemently tried out. Trying to shape such a list is an exercise in self-delusion, and psychologically dangerous. It can be done with any fringe and conspiracy theory.

@tkruse As Aristotle said, it is the mark of an educated mind that it can consider views that it does not actually hold.  You may not be able to answer the question, because of its pre-requisite that one be able to presume the ID claims are true.  As ID has no single author, one must have considered several ID authors, and boiled their collective ideas down to salient points, which one is then asked to presume to be true, and go from there.  To be ale to answer such questions in the future, you should try reading some ID writings, and critique them, NOT just read attacks on ID.

And you can build down ideas as much as you like, but this forum is not about your personal way of boiling down ideas. Present your answers clearly as a split of what philosophy says and what you personally make of it, and I won't object or downvote. It's not too much to ask.

@tkruse -- As this answer is not my personal ideas, and is instead collected from multiple ID writings, then evaluated by me under the standards of hypothesis testing vs the two most common design frames ID presents, yet you admit to have downvoted it, you description of your behavior should I do what I just did -- is clearly untrue.  I will continue to extend Aristotle's challenge to you.  Have you read any ID writings?  Are you capable of considering views you do not hold?  Do you realize you will never learn anything unless you seek out and consider ideas you do not currently agree with?

Plenty of good science for me to learn without sullying my mind with Pseudoscience. There are huge libraries full of expert knowledge that a single human can barely read in lifetime, let alone understand. So much truth available. So why spend time with puny esoteric bullshit instead, unless it were to satisfy some narcissist greed of "knowing what even experts don't know"? Even Aristotle would recognize a self-deceiving narcissist following esoteric practices instead of philosophy.

The published literature on ID is very clear in that it does not necessarily point to any god.
That is because the fundamentalist Christians sponsoring such literature through the Discovery Institute hope to change the school teaching of science, and they know making it point to a god would make courts of law declare ID as religious.
Apart from that political goal, I'd publications target doubting Christians who see that proper science explains life as possible without any designer. To reassure those Christians, ID tries to produce something that almost looks like proper science to the untrained eye (thus no direct mention of gods), but that creates a gap as a shelter for any god of the gaps. So that good Creationist can sleep in peace again, doubts averted.
Outside publications, the people who most talk about ID are Christian Creationists, so a lot of talk will revolve about how ID confirms parts of the Bible.
For no step of the evolution of life does an intelligent designer making a deliberate change any sense whatsoever as a narrative, nor does ID suggest any narrative, nor does ID suggest any model of how any such designer would have gone about their business.
Indeed purely physicalist science fiction narratives to the pseudoscience that is called ID would equally be possible, and philosophy does not assign probability to which fantasy story would be most likely to explain what does not need explaining.
In other words, yes, supernatural intervention is not more likely than natural intervention as the driving force suggested by ID writings. It's all the same and nobody in philosophy cares either way.

I haven't read much ID stuff to know if anybody makes these arguments, but here are some reasons why someone who believes in ID might infer that God - or something worth calling God - is probably the designer:

They already assign relatively high prior probability to the claim that God existed and could be the designer. They think that non-Gods who existed and could be the designer of terrestrial life have some significantly lower prior probability. In the absence of other evidence, it's obvious that the God hypothesis is statistically favored over the alien hypothesis by the ratio of the priors. This wouldn't be ID as evidence for God existing (which was taken as a prior). But it would be ID as evidence for God designing. I would guess that this best describes real ID proponents.

They think that ID was an intermittent or continuous process over billions of years. It is not plausible that any being worth associating with what we think of as "aliens" would have a multi-billion-year existence, let alone a multi-billion-year attention span.

They don't think that 4 billion years of life on Earth plus the time that non-ID-driven evolution would have taken to create a candidate designer fits in the amount of time that the universe has had places where any kind of biological evolution (high-fidelity self-replication with intermittent information-adding heritable copy errors) could take place.

As above, but they think that intelligently designed life is the only possible kind of natural life. There's no time for an infinite regress of intelligently designed natural life in a finite time history of the universe, therefore there was a non-natural first designer. God is an example of a hypothetical non-natural first designer, so this is weak evidence for God.



===

Why does Intelligent Design support God more than aliens?

Intelligent design ONLY only supports aliens.
If anything came before us , then it's  had millions and billions more years to evolve than we have. Creating a universe out of nothing by separating it into time and space components that cancel, is just the kind of thing you'd expect them to do.
I think life itself is evidence, not of God, but of a sufficiently advanced technology that is indistinguishable from magic.
I believe evolution is so obviously designed, that I feel embarrassed for the people who feel they can't acknowledge the obvious explanation.
There's no reason to link this idea to the Christian mythology, Which is ridiculous. Any similarity to gods or goddesses living or dead is purely coincidental.
I also think the main reason scientists haven't picked up on ID as being at very least, the most likely explanation, is all the crazy, stupid, or frightened  people who want to turn it into a religion.

The Intelligent Design (ID) movement does not claim to prove the existence of God. ID consists primarily of two parts: a scientific criticism of Darwinism, and a philosophical argument concerning the nature of irreducible complexity, how how life displays the markers of such complexity, and how the only known way for such complexity to arise is by intelligent design (given their prior argument that Darwinism cannot do what is required of it).
What "Darwinism" (or sometimes "neo-Darwinism") means in this field is the theory that life arose spontaneously from non-life and evolved over time by spontaneous mutation and natural selection to produce all of the various forms of life there are. ID theorists mostly use this word because if they just use "evolution", their less well-informed critics routinely misunderstand them, and react as if they were talking about nothing except the theory that it is possible for speciation to occur by spontaneous mutation and natural selection, something that most ID proponents do not dispute.
Many ID proponents are not creationists, and some of them are atheists, but clearly explaining the origins of life without Darwinism creates a serious challenge to atheism. Also, ID is used by creationists to dispute the truth of Darwinism (creationism is the theory that Genesis 1 offers an account--possibly non-literal--of the origin of the universe). These two factors make arguments about ID far more emotionally charged than they ought to be, given that ID is a purely intellectual enterprise that doesn't really effect anyone's life.
Opponents of ID often use the fact that creationists have used ID for their own purposes as an ad hominem attack on ID itself, which is clearly not a logical or even a rational response to the claims of ID. If it were, then it would be a logical, rational attack on Darwinism to point out that the Nazis used Darwinism to support their racist theories and their right to eliminate inferior (that is, less fit) races. Philosophical and scientific argumentation rejects such ad hominem arguments and insists on addressing the argument and the evidence itself, regardless of who makes the argument or who approves of it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

***a scientific criticism of Darwinism

@Groovy, how preposterous to think there could be a scientific criticism of a scientific theory.

Scientific criticism of Darwinism is sorry for my plain English bullshit. Cause all of the biology of XXth century only confirmed his main statements. Moreover Darwinism is not about the origin of life - it's about mutation and change. It looks you have not a slightest clue what you are talking about. :) It shows us that you can be totally illiterate in basic science and have lots of so called "rep" on this platform. So your answer tells us more about stackexchange, not about you. :) I don't see what to discuss with you - start with basic school biology first.

@Groovy, First of all, 20th century biology disconfirmed Darwin's theory with the discovery of DNA and they had to rework the theory on the basis of mutations rather than gradual change. In addition they have utterly failed to bridge the many gaps in the fossil record or to explain those gap plausibly. Second, I defined what I mean by "Darwinism". Bickering over terminology shows that you don't know how to engage in a scholarly debate.

@ScottRowe, your comment shows that you have no idea what goes on in the religious communities. There is an enormous amount of religious criticism of religious theories.
